# How to make a pivot table in DB2?

Tags: database, db2, pivot

I have a table be like:

```
| Date      | Week | Name   | No | Count |
|-----------|------|--------|----|-------|
| 2019/4/1  |  14  | John   | 1  | 1     |
| 2019/4/1  |  14  | Mary   | 2  | 1     |
| 2019/4/9  |  15  | Kevin  | 3  | 2     |
| 2019/4/9  |  15  | John   | 4  | 1     |
| 2019/4/9  |  15  | Jessie | 5  | 1     |
| 2019/4/18 |  16  | Kevin  | 6  | 1     |
| 2019/4/18 |  16  | John   | 7  | 1     |
| 2019/4/18 |  16  | Jessie | 8  | 2     |
| 2019/4/18 |  16  | Mary   | 9  | 3     |
| 2019/4/18 |  16  | Mary   | 10 | 1     |
| 2019/4/18 |  16  | Jessie | 11 | 1     |
| 2019/4/24 |  17  | Mary   | 12 | 1     |
| 2019/4/24 |  17  | Jessie | 13 | 1     |
```

What I want to do is to calculate people's total count per Week.
And sort by their total count.

I know GROUP BY can make this happen, I've tried, but just can't figure it out.

This is what I expect:

```
| Name   | 14 | 15 | 16 | 17 | Total |
|--------|----|----|----|----|-------|
| Mary   | 1  | 0  | 4  | 1  | 6     |
| Jessie | 0  | 1  | 3  | 1  | 5     |
| John   | 1  | 1  | 1  | 0  | 3     |
| Kevin  | 0  | 2  | 1  | 0  | 3     |
| Total  | 2  | 4  | 9  | 2  | 17    |
```

How can I do?

Comment: You can use GROUP BY and then a LATERAL JOIN to transform from vertically to horizontally your fields

Comment: https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/SQLTips4DB2LUW/entry/pivoting_tables56?lang=en

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Select [Name] 
 ,sum(case when [Week] = 14 then [Count] else 0 end) as Week14
 ,sum(case when [Week] = 15 then [Count] else 0 end) as Week15
 ,sum(case when [Week] = 16 then [Count] else 0 end) as Week16
 ,sum(case when [Week] = 17 then [Count] else 0 end) as Week17
 ,sum([Count]) as Total
from [table]
group by [Name]
order by Total
```

I'm not sure which version of DB2 you're using (LUW/zOS/i) so this is a general answer. The week number can be made to be more flexible but a certain amount of hard coding will need to be done for the number of weeks.

Comment: Thanks, it does show what I want. And yes the week number is different every week. So what do you mean "a certain amount of hard coding"?

Comment: You can make the week numbers dynamic enough to change with each week as needed with something like `(week(Current_Date) - 1)` or whatever you need. The hard coding will need to be there for the number of weeks (columns) you're reporting over. In this instance, 4 weeks. You'd need to either make the entire statement dynamic and add weeks as you need them or it'd be hard coded.

Comment: Thanks for the inspiration. I made it in my Delphi code :)